# Nativescript pass parameters to fired event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

Im using nativescript vue. Trying to pass parameters to professional ui - raddataform fired events to prevent duplicating code.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/raddataform#propertycommittedevent

Thats how looks my layout with raddataforms. You can see on every RadDataForm there is separate on event @propertyCommitted functions to fire.

```
 <StackLayout>
              <RadDataForm
                :source="aimTarget"
                @propertyCommitted="aimTargetCommitted"
                :metadata="aimTargetMetadata">
              </RadDataForm>
               <RadDataForm
                :source="fasterAimHot"
                @propertyCommitted="fasterAimHotCommitted"
                :metadata="fasterAimHotMetadata">
              </RadDataForm>
               <RadDataForm
                :source="runeAimerCrosshair"
                @propertyCommitted="runeAimerCrosshairCommitted"
                :metadata="runeAimerCrosshairMetadata">
              </RadDataForm>
        </StackLayout>
```

and for every this event there is a method which one looks like this.

```
attackMonstersCommitted (data) {

          let edited = data.object.editedObject; // it has to be performed to update radDataForm with new value object
          let tab = "attackerTab"; // to know which tab to edit
          let name = "attackMonsters";
          let property = data.object.getPropertyByName(data.propertyName);

          console.dir("valueCandidate - " + property.name);
          this.$store.commit('updateRadData', { edited , tab, name } ) // update raddataform 

          this.$update.propertyCommitted();

      },
```

So there are 4 RadDataforms and 4 methods for every one. Is there possibility to pass parameters, something like this.

```
<RadDataForm
                :source="aimTarget"
                myParameter1="PARAM1"
                @propertyCommitted="aimTargetCommitted"
                :metadata="aimTargetMetadata">
              </RadDataForm>
```

or smething like this

```
<RadDataForm
                    :source="aimTarget"
                    @propertyCommitted="aimTargetCommitted(PARAM1,PARAM2)"
                    :metadata="aimTargetMetadata">
                  </RadDataForm>
```

and then in method somehow get value of this parameters ?
Then I will be able to use one method for all raddataforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass extra parameters along with event data,

```
<RadDataForm
                :source="aimTarget"
                @propertyCommitted="aimTargetCommitted($event, 'param1', 'param2')"
                :metadata="aimTargetMetadata">
              </RadDataForm>
```

Where `$event` represents the default event objet.

Comment: yyyym. param1 is the value or name of variable? Describing precisely I want to have  param1='xxx' and pass it to method and how to retrieve in method value of this param? something like this?  console.log(data.object.param1);

Comment: his provided example they are string literals. but you could make use some other variable. If you are talking about adding properties to the @propertyCommitted event I think you would have to dig down to where that event is actually fired.
with his example. `@propertyCommitted="aimTargetCommitted($event, 'param1', 'param2')` you would need a method `aimTargetCommitted(evt, par1, par2)` which would produce the variables evt=(the original event) par1='param1' par2='param2'

Comment: good. made like u wrote. aimTargetCommitted(evt, par1, par2). In function console.log(par1) and gives 'param1' . thanks you guys very much